# Segue крашит приложение

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Имеется Navigation View Controller, от которого идет segue на Table View Controller [image: Корень всего]

В Table View Controllerе две кастомные ячейки. От каждой кнопки "(i)" идут show segue на вью-контроллер. Его содержимое значения не имеет. Хоть оно есть, хоть его нет.

[image: Связь Master View Controller с File Detail View Controller]

Так же, от Master View Controller идет segue на Tab View Controller.

[image: Tab Bar View Controller]

Так вот. При запуске это выглядит примерно так:

[image: Так выглядит приложение при запуске]

По нажатию на cell открывается редактор кода, всё как задумывалось.

[image: Редактор кода]

Но по неизвестным мне причинам, по нажатию на любую из кнопок (i) (Хотя без разницы, на какую из них нажимать, так, как это один и тот же Prototype Cell, и при вызове они выполняют один и тот же segue), происходит это...

[image: SIGABRT]

Несколько дней потратил на это. Помогите, кто разбирается. Буду очень благодарен.

UPD: Немного переписал приложение. Теперь detail-кнопка является стандартным аксессуаром, по нажатию на который вызывается функция performSegue. Оно наконец-то заработало, но только на симуляторе IOS 9.2. На IOS 10.2 на реальной машине оно по-прежнему вылетает... Я совсем перестал понимать, что происходит...

Comment: Логи ошибки приложите

Comment: @VAndrJ, Пишет только "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: Приложить минимальный проект где воспроизводится ошибка можете?

Comment: Боюсь, что нет, но я нашел логи ошибки, может вам поможет... http://pastebin.com/KLA0hrSn

Comment: Что еще на кнопке кроме segue?

Comment: Ничего... Висит prepareForSegue, который даже не вызывается... Сейчас я немного переписал приложение. Теперь кнопка Detail является не кастомной кнопкой, а стандартным аксессуаром, по нажатию на которую вызывается функция performSegue, и О, ЧУДО, оно заработало, но только на симуляторе на ios 9.2. На реальном айфона на IOS 10 оно по-прежнему вылетает именно на строке performSegue...

Comment: это то же приложение, которого код у меня есть?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Именно

Comment: работает на iphone6 ios 10.2

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ... Но не работает на IPhone SE 10.2

Comment: Походу, у вас раньше была функция `detailButtonPressed` привязанная на кнопку в классе `FileListTableCell`. Может вы удалили код в классе, но забыли удалить привязку на storyboard. По–этому когда кликаете на кнопку он пытается найти эту функцию.

Comment: @FahriAzimov Точно нет. Ошибка происходит на строке performSegue, уже успел отловить это дебаггером